# Strange behavior when subsetting with column names quoted with backticks in I of data.table

Tags: r, data.table

Look at the follow example generated with `reprex`:

```
library(data.table)

DT <- data.table(id = letters[1:3], `counts(a>=0)` = 1:3)

DT[`counts(a>=0)` >= 2]  # 1
#>    id counts(a>=0)
#> 1:  b            2
#> 2:  c            3

DT[`counts(a>=0)` == 2]  # 2
#> Error in `[.data.table`(DT, `counts(a>=0)` == 2): Column(s) [counts(a] not found in x

DT[id == "a"]  # 3
#>    id counts(a>=0)
#> 1:  a            1
```

As both the lines marked with **#1** and **#3** work, I wonder why subsetting with `` `counts(a>=0)` == 2 `` (**#2**) doesn't work.

SessionInfo:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /usr/lib/atlas-base/atlas/libblas.so.3.0
LAPACK: /usr/lib/atlas-base/atlas/liblapack.so.3.0

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] reprex_0.1.2      data.table_1.11.2

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.16     rprojroot_1.3-2  digest_0.6.15    crayon_1.3.4     withr_2.1.2      assertthat_0.2.0 R6_2.2.2        
 [8] backports_1.1.2  magrittr_1.5     formatR_1.5      evaluate_0.10.1  stringi_1.1.6    debugme_1.1.0    rstudioapi_0.7  
[15] callr_2.0.2      whisker_0.3-2    rmarkdown_1.9    devtools_1.13.5  tools_3.4.4      stringr_1.3.0    yaml_2.1.17     
[22] compiler_3.4.4   htmltools_0.3.6  memoise_1.1.0    knitr_1.20
```

Comment: How do yo find all these edge cases almost on a daily basis? I hope you are not calling your columns that way just for fun...

Comment: Anyway, the error seem to come from [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/R/data.table.R#L418). For `\`counts(a>=0)\` == 2` it builds an `on` statement of `"counts(a>=0)==counts(a>=0)" ` which fails eventually while for the rest of the options this `if` statement returns `FALSE` and goes to `else if (!is.name(isub)) i = eval(.massagei(isub), x, parent.frame())` which gives the correct result. I don't have time to investigate the `.prepareFastSubset` function but my bet that it is the source of the problem and probably the fix is not so hard too.

Comment: @mt1022, I am not sure, but I am not getting an error, I am using R 3.4.2, & data.table version 1.10.4-3, I am getting this : 
  ` id counts(a>=0)
     1:  b            2`

Comment: @PKumar, I am not getting error too with v1.10.4.3. This issue seems specific to the v1.11.2.

Comment: @mt1022, Great I hope this should be fixed(if its a problem) in near future :)

Comment: I don't think it's v1.11.2 specific rather it's an issue in all v1.11.+ . I suspect that the relevant change was introduced [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/NEWS.md#new-features-1) (bullet #15)

Comment: @DavidArenburg, I am not familiar with the internals of data.table so that I opened an [issue](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/2931) at github and briefly summarized discussions here. Hope they can find a fix soon.

Comment: Ok, I've also mentioned it [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/pull/2494#issuecomment-396533079)

Answer (score 1):

It works for me with :

```
DT[as.numeric(`counts(a>=0)`) == 2]
```

Comment: So? How does it answer the question?

Comment: Any idea why? It also seems to work with just `DT[(\`counts(a>=0)\`) == 2]`, but I can't really tell why the parsing fails in the original.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see the problem that way ! In fact it is strange that the parsing fails only for this condition, I tried with ' and "  same result...

Comment: Feel free to share your thoughts. This workaround is also helpful.